# How can I connect my bluetooth headphone (Bose QuietComfort 35 I) to my computer (Windows 7 SP1 x64)? Error message: " connection failed"

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headphones

How can I connect my bluetooth headphone (Bose QuietComfort 35 I) to my computer (Windows 7 SP1 x64)?

When I try:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I get the error message:

[image: my]

Comment: You should ask this question from your Bluetooth driver manufacturer. Standard Microsoft Bluetooth drivers on Win 7 does not support any Bluetooth Audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to remove and re-add the Bluetooth device. Not clever and not very efficient, but that's the only fix I could find:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]